# Build submission to App Store

Tags: app-store, provisioning-profile

I had submitted an app to the App Store using a certificate and provisioning profile. After submitting the app, by mistake I revoked both the certificate and provisioning profile. I have the csr and profile file with me. Can I submit a new version of my app even though I revoked the certificate and profile?

How can I update the app in the App Store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you revoked the certificate, you cannot use it or the provisioning file any more.

You would need to create a new certificate, a new provisioning file, and resubmit your app using the 2 new files.